# Verificar se a index da listbox existe?

Tags: vb.net

Olá queria saber como faço para identificar se a index (Exemplo: 5 não existe) e retornar para 0.

Segue meu código:

```
Dim avancarcoordX As Integer
avancarcoordX = lbPosX.SelectedIndex + 1
lbPosX.SelectedIndex = avancarcoordX
PosX.Text = lbPosX.SelectedItem
Dim avancarcoordY As Integer
avancarcoordY = lbPosY.SelectedIndex + 1
lbPosY.SelectedIndex = avancarcoordY
PosY.Text = lbPosY.SelectedItem
```

Quando não existe um Item então ele apresenta um erro. Preciso que ao chegar ao último item (Que é variavel) ele retorne ao primeiro. Assim um loop infinito.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite.

Tente o seguinte código:

```
    If ListBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then

        If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
            ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
        Else
            If ListBox1.SelectedIndex < ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then
                ListBox1.SelectedIndex += 1
            Else
                ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
            End If
        End If
    End If
```